# How do I get the SSL certificate for an LDAP server using StartTLS?

Tags: java, ssl, ldap

I am trying to configure my application to access an LDAP server that is listening *only* on port 389 using the StartTLS extension for security.  I want to get a copy of the SSL certificate so I can specify it as a known certificate (in a jssecacerts file, since my application is written in Java).

If it was running on port 636, I would use openssl like so:

```
openssl s_client -host myhost -port 636
```

and grab the certificate from the output.

My first though was to try using:

```
openssl s_client -host myhost -port 389 -starttls ...
```

but that doesn't support the LDAP version of starttls.

Then, I tried using ldapsearch with a high debug level:

```
ldapsearch -ZZ -h myhost -d99 ...
```

and I could see that the over-the-wire data includes the certificate, but it's not in a form that I know how to use.

Is there an easy way to get the certificate, either through command line tools or a short program?  (I don't particularly care which language, but Java would be ideal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new revision of the well-known [InstallCert](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/InstallCert) program now supports STARTTLS for several protocols, LDAP included.

Just run it like this:

```
java -jar installcert-usn-20131123.jar host_name:389
```

and it will save the certificate for you in the `jssecacerts` keystore file in your JRE file tree, and also in the `extracerts` keystore file in your current directory. You can then use Java [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) to export the certificate(s) to other formats.

You are welcome to visit my blog page [Yet another InstallCert for Java, now with STARTTLS support](http://s-n-ushakov.blogspot.com/2013/11/yet-another-installcert-for-java-now.html) for download and instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a connect as described in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/StartTlsResponse.html), using the sample code at the top.
2. That gives you the `SSLSession,` from which you can get the peer certificate chain, from which you can get the `X509Certificate` of the peer as element zero.
3. Then save that wherever you need to, using `Certificate.getEncoded()` to get the certificate as a `byte[]` array. Or you could add it directly to a new or old `KeyStore` object and save that.

Answer (score 0):

We have documented [some of the different methods](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Obtain%20a%20Certificate%20from%20Server).

And yes, openSSL last time I looked STILL does not have the ability to use the LDAP ptotocol for starttls option. It should be like:

```
openssl s_client -connect remote.host:25 -starttls LDAP
```

Comment: Now, the command `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ldap.hostname.domain.ext:636` works for me with OpenSSL version `1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` (from my CentOS). Like explained in your linked page.